# How to publish asp.net core application on linux or mac os?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-webapi

> I am creating one asp.net core application on widows platform using
> visual studio.I want to publish this application on Linux and mac os.
>
> **How can I do this and what configuration is required?**

Comment: Follow this link http://hintdesk.com/net-core-how-to-publish-an-asp-net-core-application-to-linux-host/

Comment: @parvezalamkhan:But I want to do restoration of packages.building of the application on windows platform for Linux or mac os and in above link it is self hosted application then publish on nginx server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/linuxproduction

tested and working. you can also copy the project in linux distro then you can do dotnet restore and publish